# aws s3 static website endpoint redirection issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I have created a s3 bucket named xyz.com (Note:I didn't registered this domain) and uploaded index.html in it, given public permissions. from the properties section, enabled static website hosting and tested the endpoint it is working fine.

For bucket redirection, I have created www.xyz.com bucket and from the properties section, we have enabled redirection  and given xyz.com as the redirection. When I click redirection endpoint, it is showing an error and not loadnig www.xyz.com.

xyz.com - s3 static website endpoint is working.
www.xyz.com - S3 static website is not working in browser. Site is not opening.

Curl command output to www.xyz.com

```
curl -I http://www.xyz.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com 

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
x-amz-id-2: iEF0Wpr8Nbx5WUuzztLMMLFvC/EfldkeuKe7sKwCAYIxKnssLibUHqdN8YH9CXbNVEFG/uy7elw=
x-amz-request-id: C8819F6399B37586 
Date: Mon, 06 Nov 2017 01:02:37 GMT 
Location: http://mydingdongbucket.com/ 
Content-Length: 0 
Server: AmazonS3
```

What am I missing?

note: I Didn't create any hosted zone for xyz.com. All I want to test is, S3 enpoint redirections.

Comment: *"All I want to test is, S3 enpoint redirections."*  It seems to be working perfectly, according to the curl output.  You can't redirect to a non-existent site and expect something other than an error to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 static web sites have specific bucket naming requirements.

If your domain name is www.mydomain.com then you must create a bucket with the name www.mydomain.com. Anything else will not work.

Like domains, subdomains must have their own S3 buckets, and the buckets must share the exact names as the subdomains.

Here is a link that walks you thru creating an S3 static web site.

[Setting up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)

Comment: Thank you for reply @John. But I am using same name as per DNS standards. Like xyz.com & www.xyz.com. No issue with them. 

I have also followed the documentation and doing the same steps but I din't implemented route 53 steps because, I want to test if S3 bucket redirection is working or not i.e, till the point 2.5 from the http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html link.